# How to zoom in on a subset from a plot (in matplotlib)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subset

I am looping through my dataframe and plotting the top 5 most active user's scores over time. Here is the code I have to plot. It plots successfully but I want to create a subplot (not sure if that is the correct term, perhaps subset plot) that will essentially zoom into 90% to 100%. To clarify it will zoom in on 90 to 100% for the y-axis (which is in this case is `score`), which normally ranges from 0 to 1. How can I do this simply using matplotlib without changing much of what I have thus far?

```
user_id_list = df.groupby('user_id').count( ['post'].sort_values(ascending = False).index[:5]
for uid in user_id_list:
    df_sub = df.query(f'user_id=="{uid}"')
    df_sub.set_index('date')['score'].plot('-', label=uid)
```

Code we be appreciated since I am not too familiar! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [**`xlim`**](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

```
user_id_list = df.groupby('user_id').count( ['post'].sort_values(ascending = False).index[:5]
for uid in user_id_list:
    df_sub = df.query(f'user_id=="{uid}"')
    df_sub.set_index('date')['score'].plot('-', label=uid)
    plt.xlim([.9, 1])  # <--- I added this
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed to ylim instead, but otherwise this was great :)

Comment: @JaneSully Glad I could help.